# Laravel 5.1 mocking 'unique' validation rule

Tags: php, validation, unit-testing, laravel, laravel-5.1

We are using the 'unique' rule for validation on the application, but for tests we're mocking the database layer through the use of repository pattern. Is there a way to mock the `unique` rule so that it doesn't attempt to check the database?

I tried mocking `Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateUnique` it doesn't work but since the method is protected.

Answer (score 2):

**unique** rule, along with a few other rules (e.g. **exists**) uses **presence verifier** to do validation checks. By default **DatabasePresenceVerifier** is used. It implements **PresenceVerifierInterface** that consists of 2 methods. You could mock methods of that verifier and use it during tests. You can access the verifier with

```
\Validator::getPresenceVerifier()
\Validator::setPresenceVerifier()
```