# How can I mock unique validation rule?

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, laravel-5.1

I am writing test cases for a `store()` function of a `ResourceController` which adds a new resource in database.

I am not allowed to access database in my test cases, So I am mocking all the database interactions & now I need to mock the `unique` validation rule.

I have Googled it & even searched on the stackoverflow but I didn't
 found anything specific.

**Here is what I know:-** 
I can mock the `\Validator::getPresenceVerifier() &
\Validator::setPresenceVerifier()` but if I mock them, then i will not be able to make the validator object. [StackOverflow Question Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600605/laravel-5-1-mocking-unique-validation-rule)

Can anyone guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here are some ideas for you: First, the Validator is a facade, which means you can mock any method of it with Validator::shouldReceive. You can also mock the whole root object with `Validator::swap($mock)`. If your controller is using `$this->validate`, you can also mock the validator by replacing the internal validator instance - I suspect you might even be able to use the IoC container to inject it when you create the controller.

If all else fails, you can also test the method by creating a mock of the controller, and then calling the method on your controller mock - that way you can mock other internal methods (e.g. the validation). You can test the method directly, or use `App::bind` again to map your mock so that it triggers from the call method.

If you are validating with a custom Request class, you can also try mocking that one to disable the validation entirely, or replace it with your own validator using a custom validation function instead of the unique test.

Comment: I am using `Validator::make()` function to validate my data. Can you please provide me an example code in reference to your suggestion (If it's not too much to ask). I am still unable to understand you completely.

Comment: @ManishYadav make() gets you a validator object, it doesn't do the validation (yet). So first create a mock object $mock, and have it override the fails method to return false. Then use `Validator::shouldReceive('make')->andReturn($mock)` so that the call to Validator::make will return your mock object. The controller will call make(), and get the mock object, then call fails(), which you've mocked, so it will think the validation passes without doing it.

Comment: @Benuibird, but  I also want to test other validations, I only wants to override the `unique` validation, other validations should be validated

Comment: @ManishYadav It sounds like what you really want, is to mock the database connection instead. If you want everything else to behave normally. Try that instead.