# Skip Laravel's FormRequest Validation

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I've recently added [HaveIBeenPwned](https://github.com/valorin/pwned-validator) to my form request class to check for cracked passwords. Given that this makes an external API call, is there a way for me to skip either this validation rule or the FormRequest class altogether during testing?

Here's the request I make in my test.

```
    $params = [
        'first_name' => $this->faker->firstName(),
        'last_name' => $this->faker->lastName(),
        'email' => $email,
        'password' => '$password',
        'password_confirmation' => '$password',
        'terms' => true,
        'invitation' => $invitation->token
    ];


    $response = $this->json('POST', '/register-invited', $params);
```

The functionality I'm testing resides on a controller. In my test I POST an array of data that passes through a FormRequest with the following rules.

```
 public function rules()
 {
 return [
  'first_name' => 'required|string|max:70',
  'last_name' => 'required|string|max:70',
  'email' => 
  'required|email|unique:users,email|max:255|exists:invitations,email',
  'password' => 'required|string|min:8|pwned|confirmed',
   'is_trial_user' => 'nullable|boolean',
   'terms' => 'required|boolean|accepted',
    ];
  }
```

I want to override the 'pwned' rule on the password so I can just get to the controller without having to worry about passing validation.

Comment: See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mocking. It may take a little digging, but mocking the specific API call your validator is making will mean you can still use automated testing for the FormRequest.

Comment: I've read through that, I'm not really sure where to start. It's worth noting that I'm relatively new Laravel.

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44586700/7528944) will help you get started? If you can't figure it out, may I suggest posting the validation code in question and the context from where it is called?

Comment: @PtrTon I've updated my question to add more context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the information provided I'd say you are executing an integration test which does an actual web request. In such a context I'd say it's fine for your test suite to connect to a 3rd party since that's part of 'integrating'.

In case you still prefer to mock the validation rule you could [swap out the Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44586114/how-can-i-mock-unique-validation-rule/44586700#44586700) using either the `swap`

```
$mock = Mockery::mock(Validator::class);
$mock->shouldReceive('some-method')->andReturn('some-result');
Validator::swap($mock);
```

Or by replacing its instance in the service container

```
$mock = Mockery::mock(Validator::class);
$mock->shouldReceive('some-method')->andReturn('some-result');
App::bind($mock);
```

Alternatively you could mock the Cache::remember() call which is an interal part of the [Pwned validation rule itself](https://github.com/valorin/pwned-validator/blob/master/src/Pwned.php). Which would result into something like

```
Cache::shouldReceive('remember')
   ->once()
   ->andReturn(new \Illuminate\Support\Collection([]));
```

Comment: Woohooo! That did it. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I was able to get the `Cache` option to work but for the first suggestion, I'm confused about the inputs. Do I actually use the `Validator` class, or do I use the `Pwned` class?

Comment: Unfortunately the `Validator::swap` and `App:bind` methods only support replacing the entire `Validator` class, so you'll have to mock each call to it. The `Pwned` class can't be mocked from what I know since only Laravel facades and services in the servicecontainer can be mocked.

Comment: Prefer `Validator::shouldReceive('some-method')->andReturn('some-result');` instead of creating a mock, and swaping it

Answer (score 0):

The `Illuminate\Validation\Validator` instance is actually created from `make()` of `Illuminate\Validation\Factory` class (which implements `Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Factory`).

=> So you need to manipulate the creation of `Validator` instance through `Factory` class.

Here is how I mock it:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Factory as ValidationFactory;
use Illuminate\Validation\Factory;

/** @var \Mockery\MockInterface|\Mockery\LegacyMockInterface $mock */
$mock = Mockery::mock(Factory::class);
$mock = $mock->makePartial()->shouldAllowMockingProtectedMethods();
$this->app->bind(ValidationFactory::class, function () use ($mock) {
    return $mock;
});
//`make` is called at \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest >> createDefaultValidator()
$mock->shouldReceive('make')->once()->andReturn(new Validator(
    app()->make(\Illuminate\Contracts\Translation\Translator::class),
    data: [
        "star" => 1,
        "coin" => 2,
    ],
    rules: [
        "star" => [], //must be empty so that validation process would not trigger.
        "coin" => [],
    ] //adding `rules` param here so that  $request->validated() can be called later.
));
```