# Database entry not saved during unit tests when mocked request

Tags: laravel, mocking, phpunit

```
$post= factory(Model)->make();
$this->post(route("post.store", $post->toArray()))->assertSee($model->name);
$this->assertDatabaseHas($this->table, $model->toArray());
```

This code works. But if we mocked request:

```
$this->mock(PostRequest::class, function ($mock) {
   $mock->shouldReceive('passes')->andReturn(true);
});
```

in this case an empty database error is returned

The table is empty..

> Blockquote

How can this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have anything in the database, as you are actually not persisting anything there. I suppose that in `post.store` controller you have logic for persisting that `model`, and that's why it passes.

In your mock, you don't persist anything to the database, you just basically say, receive `passes` and return `true` and nothing else happens, therefore, nothing is saved to the database, which is the reason why `$this->assertDatabaseHas($this->table, $model->toArray());` will tell you that model is not persisted, as it tests against the test database content.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes in `post.store` controller I save model. I thought that I fake only validation.
Is there a way to make logic from a controller and fake only validation?

Comment: Yep, you can do it. Here is the reference on how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57381415/7770919

Answer (score 0):

The `make` method doesn't save the post to the database, it just creates the model.
Use the `create` method instead to save it to the database.

Change this:

```
$post= factory(Model)->make();
```

To this:

```
$post= factory(Model)->create();
```

Comment: This is clear. in `post.store` controller I save model